# Unix - Pipe, forks, execlp, dup2, c program

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, fork

This is for an assignment. I am new to programming in unix and could use some help. I need to create a C program that does the following:

***In the main() function, it creates a pipe using the pipe() function, then creates two child processes with fork(). Child 1 redirects stdout to the write end of the pipe and then executes with execlp() the "ps -aux" command. Child 2 redirects its input from stdin to the read end of the pipe, then it executes the "sort -r -n -k 5" command.
After creating both children, the parent process waits for them to terminate before it can exit.
Note that you may have to create Child 2 first, followed by Child 1.
The parent program does the same thing as a shell that runs the command "ps -aux | sort -r -n -k 5". You must use the fork(), pipe(), dup2(), close(), execlp() functions (or other exec() variation).***

I am a senior year CS student and pretty savvy with windows programming, so I'm not asking for a solution, just a translation as to what exactly needs to be done and what the various commands all mean.

Thanks

Comment: In Linux the standard way to find out what a command does is to read the "man pages". From a shell type `man <command>`. Same works for (most) library functions. The man pages are also available online so you can search for it in a browser if you prefer that way.

Comment: You can find all of the "commands" (by which I presume you mean "functions") in the `man` pages. If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help. As a senior year CS student, you should know how to contact that instructor by now. We're glad to help with homework, as long as they meet the criteria in the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* You're asking for a tutorial in C programming for *nix systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to be done:

Main Process

- create a pipe (see: `man pipe()`)
- start 2 child processes (see: `man fork`)
- wait for both of them to exit (see: `man wait`)
- exit

Chid 1

- redirect stdout to write end of pipe (see: `man dup`)
- run ps -aux (see: `man exec`)
- exit

Child 2

- redirect read end of pipe to stdin
- run sort -r -n -k
- exit

Regarding `execlp` you will find relevant info in the manual page. (`man exec`). Most interesting pnrt to answer your question quoted below:

Probably the most important thing to be done **RTFM**.

> The initial argument for these functions is the name of a file that is to be executed. 
>   The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Especially don't forget the last sentence and end the parameters of your call `execlp("ps", "ps", "-aux", NULL);` or whatever it may be with `NULL`.

Comment: Don't worry. It's about trying to help people, not about making points. Don't forget to take a look into the manual pages, especially if you are new to UNIX, you'll be surprised about the amount of information you' ll be able to find there. I tried to copy most important of `man exec` into the answer. Make sure to read the other pages mentioned as well. Welcome to the UNIX world, enjoy and you'll never want to leave it again.